# RecyclerView Can't Scroll horizontally, but work on Vertical (Failed load image)

Tags: java, android

I want to make my recycleview slide horizontally not vertical.
When i try to make it vertical it displayed all of the 8 items, but when i tried to make it Horizontal it only displayed 2 items and Error

WHEN I TRIED TO USE VERTICAL IT DISPLAYED all 8 items as i wanted.

recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(),LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false));

But when i change to HORIZONTAL
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(),LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false));

It only load 2 image, i can't scroll horizontally to the next image and it displayed Error like this.

W/Choreographer: OPTS_INPUT: First frame was drawed before optimized, so skip!

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

```
private static final String TAG = "HomeFragment";

//Vars
private ArrayList<String> mImage = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> mTitle = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> mDesc = new ArrayList<>();

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // initialize container view
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    // pass container view to bitmap images so that will use to initialize recyclerView
    initBitmapImages(view);

    return view;
}



private void initBitmapImages(View view){
    Log.d(TAG, "initBitmapImages: preparing bitmaps");

    mImage.add("https://i.redd.it/j6myfqglup501.jpg");
    mTitle.add("Foto 1");
    mDesc.add("This is foto 1");

    mImage.add("https://i.redd.it/j6myfqglup501.jpg");
    mTitle.add("Foto 2");
    mDesc.add("This is foto 2");

    mImage.add("https://i.redd.it/j6myfqglup501.jpg");
    mTitle.add("Foto 3");
    mDesc.add("This is foto 3");

    mImage.add("https://i.redd.it/j6myfqglup501.jpg");
    mTitle.add("Foto 4");
    mDesc.add("This is foto 4");

    mImage.add("https://i.redd.it/j6myfqglup501.jpg");
    mTitle.add("Foto 5");
    mDesc.add("This is foto 5");

    mImage.add("https://i.redd.it/j6myfqglup501.jpg");
    mTitle.add("Foto 6");
    mDesc.add("This is foto 6");

    mImage.add("https://i.redd.it/j6myfqglup501.jpg");
    mTitle.add("Foto 7");
    mDesc.add("This is foto 7");

    mImage.add("https://i.redd.it/j6myfqglup501.jpg");
    mTitle.add("Foto 8");
    mDesc.add("This is foto 8");

    initRecyclerView(view);
}
private void initRecyclerView(View view){
    Log.d(TAG, "initRecyclerView: init recyclerView");

    RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(mImage,mTitle,mDesc,getContext());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(),LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false));
}
```

I hope i could scroll horizontally to this recycleview and load all 8 image Thanks :)

Comment: usually i add `recyclerView.notifyChanged();` to refresh the view

Comment: in which part of code do you add that if its in my case ?

Comment: after u set all things of `recyclerView`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Picasso or Glide for loading pictures like this

```
Picasso.get().load(imageList.getItem(position)).into(imageView);
```

And for us to answer you more precisely you could have provided the code of your ViewHolder.

Hope this one helps.

Comment: i did use glide like this
--------
Glide.with(mContext)
                    .asBitmap()
                    .load(mImage.get(position))
                    .into(holder.image);

When i do this on Vertical mode it work fine, but when i change it into horizontal. It can't load the rest of the image only 2/8 and it output an error/warning 
**W/Choreographer: OPTS_INPUT: First frame was drawed before optimized, so skip!**

Comment: Try to use placeholder image in order the Android to calculate the actual dimens of the image on the event of showing it to the screen. Glide can do it. Maybe it will work.

Answer (score 0):

private void initRecyclerView(View view){
    Log.d(TAG, "initRecyclerView: init recyclerView");
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
    = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(mImage,mTitle,mDesc,getContext());
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

recyclerView .setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
}